# Linux Mint: ACPI PCC probe and usb descriptor errors during boot

Tags: boot, usb, acpi

I'm getting a lot of errors during bootup on Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64 bit. For the most time, I've been able to boot (the error messages just flash and disappear) with no problems with my system. A few times, Mint hasn't booted up, now being one of those times. The error messages are as follows:

```
[0.668973] ACPI PCC probe failed.

and

[2.135031] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/all, error -71.
```

When I pressed the power button (just once) I get this:

```
[21.3186(or 06)50] ACPI: _SB_.PCI0.SBRG.ASOC: Device cannot be
configured due to a frequency mismatch.
```

I read on another question on Askubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed) that the "ACPI PCC probe failed" error is "harmless" so I guess that's not a problem (I didn't read it very thoroughly).

But it'd be nice to find out the cause of the two other errors. I'll help to my best ability, of course. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://urukrama.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/usb-drive-not-recognised-error-71/

Comment: I made a new options.conf file in that directory and pasted that line of code in there but I'm not sure whether it helped or not. I removed my bluetooth adapter which I suspected to be the cause of the error, maybe it was doing that that fixed it. I'll do some testing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACPI PCC probe failed.` means that your mainboard doesn't support a relatively new (specified in 2011) feature called "Platform Communication Channel". It's only a debug message and completely harmless.

`usb 4-2: device descriptor read/all, error -71.` means that an USB device was detected but could not be initialized at boot. There's probably a faulty USB device connected to your computer or it's an old device that only supports an old initialization scheme (See the comment by @munircontractor). You might be able to identify the device by running `lsusb -s 4:$(cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-2/devnum)`.

`ACPI: _SB_.PCI0.SBRG.ASOC: Device cannot be configured due to a frequency mismatch.` means that a PCI card in your computer is incompatible with the PCI bus because it runs with another frequency, possibly because it's too old. As the error message names the event source `PCI0` it's probably the first (topmost) PCI slot. Normally this error should only occur when the system boots or when a PCI card is hotplugged. It's strange that it occurs when pressing the power button. That might be hinting at more complex hardware errors or BIOS bugs.

The PCI error is the most probable candidate for being related with your boot problems. If you have any PCI expansion cards in your computer, you should take a look at them and try if removing the one in the topmost PCI slot or moving it to another slot helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the USB device that caused the usb descriptor error was a cheap bluetooth receiver. I removed it and everything worked after that. I'm able to boot again. The PCI error is weird as the only PCI device I have is my Geforce 9600 GT graphics card. I might consider moving it, if you think that will help. We'll see.

Comment: Good to hear that removing the bluetooth receiver helped. Your Geforce 9600 GT is probably unrelated. It should be connected via PCI Express but the error refers to the (old) PCI bus. It's probably a BIOS bug that might get fixed with a BIOS update or some hardware fault on the mainboard itself. If the system freezes again even without connected USB devices, you should consider replacing the mainboard.